# org.openrdf.query.MalformedQueryException for SparQL insert

Tags: insert, sparql, ontology, triples

I've read ways on how to insert data using SPARQL. Some references use *INSERT* while other references use *INSERT DATA*. So, I'm confused on how will I do the query. My goal is to insert a data property which is the *CourseName* to a class "Course" in my ontology. Here is my query:

```
INSERT{
    <http://www.semanticweb.org/rocky/ontologies/2015/3/CurriculumOntology#Course> curr:CourseName "IT222".
            }
```

I've tried this query and an exception appears which says:

```
SparqlReasonerException: org.openrdf.query.MalformedQueryException: Encountered " "insert" "INSERT "" at line 9, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
    "base" ...
    "prefix" ...
    "select" ...
    "construct" ...
    "describe" ...
    "ask" ...
```

is the subject of the triple wrong? or what should i really need to put on the subject of the triple? and why does an exception appears? btw, I'm using Protege in modeling my ontology.

Comment: It looks like you're issuing a SPARQL *UPDATE* to something which is expecting a SPARQL *QUERY* instead. In SPARQL (and unlike SQL) you can't INSERT / DELETE etc where a query is expected.

Answer (score 3):

> *I've read ways on how to insert data using SPARQL. Some references use **INSERT** while other references use **INSERT DATA**.*

There's **insert data** for inserting literal data into a graph, and there's a more complicated **delete/insert** (which requires at least one **delete** or **insert**, but you don't have to do both), which will let you do **insert { … } where { … }**.  These are defined in the standard which is freely available online;  you don't have to resort to secondary sources.  The standard defines [**insert data**](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#insertData) with syntax:

> **INSERT DATA**  *QuadData*

and [**delete/insert**](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#deleteInsert) with syntax:

> ( **WITH** *IRIref* )?
> ( ( *DeleteClause* *InsertClause*? ) | *InsertClause* )
> ( **USING** ( **NAMED** )? *IRIref* )*
> **WHERE** *GroupGraphPattern*
>
> *DeleteClause* ::= **DELETE**  *QuadPattern*
> *InsertClause* ::= **INSERT**  *QuadPattern*

So yours is a simple syntax error. You need **INSERT DATA**, not **DELETE/INSERT**.  Thus:

```
INSERT DATA {
  <http://www.semanticweb.org/rocky/ontologies/2015/3/CurriculumOntology#Course> curr:CourseName "IT222".
}
```

You can check syntax with [sparql.org's update validator](http://sparql.org/update-validator.html).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for mine five cents. But perhaps it's a result of wrong "GET" or "POST" request to the SPARQL server.

Try to catch request to the server. In mine case I managed to the same issue after request string correction.

```
.../sparql?query=...
```

to

```
.../sparql?update=...
```

I believe that Protege has the option to send update data query correctly.